# Typescript declaration of decomposed class

Tags: typescript

I have a I am trying to create a typing for a node module. I found that when I am using decomposed class, the code is not compiling.

This is my declaration file **demo.d.ts**

```
declare namespace DemoNs {
  interface Foo_static {
    new(): Foo_instance;
  }

  interface Foo_instance {}

  export var Foo: Foo_static;
}


declare module 'demo-ns' {
  export = DemoNs
}
```

and this is my test file **demo-tests.ts**

```
/// <reference path="demo.d.ts" />

import { Foo } from 'demo-ns';

var a: Foo;
```

When trying to compile last line of the test file says:

```
error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Foo'.
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem.

The compiler throw the error because even tough I exported Foo, there is no place saying it's a type. And therefore he isn't finding Foo.

I fixed by adding to my namespace Foo in my declaration file, the line:

```
export type Foo = Foo_instance;
```